# Create hierarchy layout in cytoscape js that allows parent child relationships?

Tags: javascript, graph, visualization, cytoscape.js

For instance I want to visualise my graph in level order hierarchy, but each node can have multiple parents and children, and i want to be able to traverse the graph in the GUI by selecting 2 nodes.

Currently the 'breadthfirst' layout allows hierarchy, while the 'cose' layout allows compound nodes (nodes that can have multiple parents and children). Is there a way to tweak the source code for either, or to make my own custom layout from scratch for cytoscape?

Answer (score 3):

Try the existing layouts:

- http://js.cytoscape.org/#layouts
- http://js.cytoscape.org/#extensions/layout-extensions

`breadthfirst` and `dagre` are DAG-specific layouts.  `cola` supports DAG-like flow, but it's a force-directed layout.

Or write your own layout: http://js.cytoscape.org/#extensions/api